# load html file in requirejs path config

Tags: javascript, html, css, requirejs

I am new to require js please excuse me if this is a silly doubt but I am trying to load the html files using require js text plugin. But the issue is when I try to load my template file using the path variable somehow when the browser renders the file it gets prepended by ".".

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 0,
    baseUrl: gadgetHome,
    paths: {
        'Charts': 'ChartsAll',
        'gadget-js': 'gadget',
        'gadget-css': gadgetHome + '/css/gadget',
        'default-css': gadgetHome + '/css/default',
        'print-css': gadgetHome + '/css/print',
        'gadget-html': gadgetHome + '/gadget.html'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'css': '/Libraries/require-css/css.js',
            'text': '/Libraries/require-text/2.0.0/text.js',
        }
    }
});
when the files are rendered in the browser all files loads properly but the gadget.html(it loads as /.gadget.html and then gives 404)
//load//
require(['Charts', 'text!gadget-html', 'css!gadget-css', 'css!default-css', 'css!print-css'],
        function(undefined, html) {
            $j("body").append(html);
            require(['gadget-js']);
        }
```